# User-defined Policy Evaluates to True when Evaluated but False when Invoked by Test-SqlAvailabilityReplica

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, high-availability, policy-based-management

I created a PBM condition and policy in SSMS. The policy runs a T-SQL script using the ExecuteSql function against the Server facet to determine whether all databases that are expected to be a member of an availability group are in fact members of the group. The expected values are stored in a table. SQL below; it executes fine.

When I evaluate the policy (right-click | Evaluate) it shows success. The actual and expected values are zero. So far, so good.

[image]

The policy is configured to be in the Availability Replica warnings category so it can be evaluated by the High Availabiltiy dashboard (or the Test-SqlAvailabilityReplica cmdlet). When I run the High Availabilty dashboard it reports a policy execution running the policy but gives no further detail. See 2nd screen capture in image.

When I run the Test-SqlAvailabilityReplica cmdlet in Powershell it reports a value of False for the policy. All other policies report True (3rd screen capture). When I run the cmdlet with the -Verbose parameter I don't see the SQL for my policy being executed but I do see the SQL for the other policies. It appears that is returns False without being evaluated. I'm running as a user with sysadmin.

I'm stumped. Why is it returning False when it should be True? Any insight appreciated.

Condition:

```
ExecuteSql('numeric', 'SELECT 
       count(*)
FROM myDB.dbo.AvailabilityGroups ag
    INNER JOIN myDB.dbo.AvailabilityGroupDatabases agd
        ON ag.AvailabilityGroupId = agd.AvailabilityGroupId
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT name,
               database_name
        FROM master.sys.availability_groups ag
            INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_databases_cluster adc
                ON ag.group_id = adc.group_id
    ) sag
        ON ag.AvailabilityGroupName = sag.name
           AND agd.DatabaseName = sag.database_name
WHERE sag.name IS NULL
      AND sag.database_name IS NULL')
```

Comment: If you want any credible answer you will need to give more details.  Can you post the script?  What it is evaluating?